# Show button certain times/days every week

Tags: javascript, php

I need to show a button on my site only certain days/times

**For ex:**

Sunday - `8am-8pm`
Monday - `Dont Show`
Tuesday - `7pm-9pm`
Wednseday - `4pm-11pm`

*and so on* (repeats every week)

How can i achieve this? (using javascript or php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: @ashkufaraz, what does this have to do with a cron job?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way in php:

```
$show_times = array(
    array('sunday 8am', 'sunday 8pm'),
    array('tuesday 7pm', 'tuesday 9pm'),
    array('wednesday 4pm', 'wednesday 11pm')
);

$now = time();
$show = false;

foreach ($show_times as $time) {
    $from = strtotime($time[0]);
    $to = strtotime($time[1]);

    if ($now >= $from and $now <= $to) {
        $show = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($show) {
    echo '<button>the button</button>';
}
```